PyCharm not recognizing Flask-WTF import
I'm encountering an issue in PyCharm where it's not recognizing the Flask-WTF import statement in my Flask project. Specifically, I have Flask-WTF version 1.0.0 installed in my Python environment, but PyCharm is showing a red line under from flask_wtf import FlaskForm.
Here's a snippet of my requirements.txt file:
blinker==1.7.0
Bootstrap-Flask==2.2.0
certifi==2024.2.2
charset-normalizer==3.3.2
click==8.1.7
colorama==0.4.6
Flask==2.3.2
Flask-WTF==1.0.0
idna==3.6
itsdangerous==2.2.0
Jinja2==3.1.3
MarkupSafe==2.1.5
packaging==24.0
pillow==10.2.0
python-dotenv==1.0.1
requests==2.31.0
urllib3==2.2.1
webdriver-manager==4.0.1
Werkzeug==3.0.0
WTForms==3.0.1

I've already verified that Flask-WTF is installed correctly using pip list, and the package is indeed listed there. I've also tried the following troubleshooting steps:

Cleared PyCharm's cache using File > Invalidate Caches / Restart... > Invalidate and Restart.
Re-imported the project into PyCharm.
Ensured that PyCharm is using the correct Python interpreter and that it matches the one where Flask-WTF is installed.
Updated PyCharm to the latest version and checked for updates.

Despite these efforts, the issue persists. I'm not sure what else to try, and any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance for your help!
Best regards,
Ruth Blossom

I don't think you will get any concrete advice except to double check your environment and python interpreter. Try to run your program without pycharm. Then you would know something is misconfigured in pycharm.

Here's a step-by-step guide on how I resolved my Flask import issues:
I initially received an error saying "The system cannot find the path specified" when trying to activate my virtual environment. Here's how I resolved it:

First, I ensured I was in the correct project directory:
cd C:\Users\Name\PycharmProjects\ProjectName


I created a new virtual environment using the following command:
python -m venv myenv


To activate the virtual environment, I used:
myenv\Scripts\activate

This time, it successfully activated the virtual environment.


I mistakenly combined the installation command with the run command. Here’s how I corrected it:

I installed Flask-WTF using the following command:
pip install -U Flask-WTF


I set the FLASK_APP environment variable to point to my main application file:
set FLASK_APP=main.py


Finally, I started the Flask application using:
flask run



By following these steps, I was able to successfully activate my virtual environment and run my Flask application without any issues. I hope this helps anyone facing similar problems
